# How to run an Alpha Build?

Tags: windows, installation, versions

This would seem to be a dumb question since I can't find anyone asking it before....
I thought I would install an Alpha build for the first time (2.93 - on a Windows PC). I unzipped all files to a different directory from 2.92 but I cannot find the exe file to run it!
Should I have installed all the files to the 2.92 directory? Was really hesitant to do that since I want to be able to remove it easily, if necessary. I would think it not necessary to do this since if I never had Blender installed prior how would I run an Alpha build?

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. Mark the answer that 
helped you as accepted instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBQh7.png). 
Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Read also: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The alpha build should have an EXE file, if you downloaded it to a Windows computer.

If you used a different OS to download it, the website may have selected a different binary format. Alpha and beta builds should always be able to be run simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, but it definitely doesn't. If I go into the directory for 2.92 I see all kinds of files including the Blender.exe, however in the 2.93 directory there is just ONE file - python39.dll (and some other directories, of course, but none have the exe file.)

Comment: @lensman ok, that is an extraction error, a download error, or something that isn’t on your end. Try re-downloading the archive: the binary file SHOULD be there.

Comment: And I just double checked - it was the correct OS file I downloaded. Windows zip file uploaded at 29 May 2021 05:47:30

Comment: "that is an extraction error, a download error, or something that isn’t on your end. Try re-downloading the archive: the binary file SHOULD be there. – ZargulTheWizard"  Thanks. I guess that is all I can try.

Comment: There must have been something going wrong. I always download the zip from alphas or betas, unpack it and in the blender directory there are all kinds of files which looks just like the regular install, including the blender.exe program file.

Comment: SOLVED (I think). Checked my download file and it was only 79MB in size and should have been much larger!